# Can't create entity with Hibernate. SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, hibernate

I spent the whole day to solve this problem. An error occurs on line with `session.getTransaction().commit();`

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

@Override
public void initGroup(Group group) throws BotException {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(group);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (PersistenceException e)
    {
        throw new BotException("You are already registred");
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
```

**Surprisingly, I have the same function for "Station" entity, but it works fine**

It's strange so much. I don't know how to solve it.

It's my Group.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group")
public class Group {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String telegramId;
    private int experience;
    private int money;
    private String nowStation;

    public Group() {}

public Group(String name, String password, String telegramId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.telegramId = telegramId;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "telegram_id", nullable = false, length = 45)
public String getTelegramId() {
    return telegramId;
}

public void setTelegramId(String telegramId) {
    this.telegramId = telegramId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "experience", nullable = true)
public int getExperience() {
    return experience;
}

public void setExperience(int experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "money", nullable = true)
public int getMoney() {
    return money;
}

public void setMoney(int money) {
    this.money = money;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "now_station", nullable = true, length = 45)
public String getNowStation() {
    return nowStation;
}

public void setNowStation(String nowStation) {
    this.nowStation = nowStation;
}
```

and hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/game_data_base</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">*******</property>
        <mapping class="model.Group"/>
        <mapping class="model.Station"/>
        <mapping class="model.User"/>
        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Errors

```
сен 25, 2016 7:42:54 PM org.telegram.telegrambots.logging.BotLogger severe
19:42:54.374 [PMPUTestBot Telegram Executor] DEBUG org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl - Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
SEVERE: BOTSESSION
19:42:54.374 [PMPUTestBot Telegram Executor] INFO org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/game_data_base]
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
19:42:54.374 [PMPUTestBot Telegram Executor] DEBUG org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl - Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1411)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3168)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2382)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at dao.GroupDaoImpl.initGroup(GroupDaoImpl.java:32)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: add the errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group` is an SQL keyword. Rename your table to something else

```
@Table(name = "my_group")
```

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept this answer if you found it useful